# RFT- What JAR file do i need to use 'import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder'

Tags: jar, xml-parsing, rft, ibm-rational

On my scenario, I'm trying to retrieve the information of an applicant from an XML file. I'm trying to retrieve the data of certain tags within the xml file and insert the string to an CSV file to use it as the datapool.

Im trying to use the following Imports

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;  
import javaxxml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;  
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
```

When i try to use the above import classes i get an error (The import cannot be resolved)

I have added the JAR file **JDOM** to my project , but that didn't work.

> I was using **"java"** instead of **"javax"** i'm no longer getting the error

Comment: At least write your question in the textarea and some more details about what you've tried and the result(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) tells me it's in [rt.jar](http://www.javacodebook.com/2013/08/13/what-is-rt-jar-what-constitutes-jdk-and-jre/) (as of Java 6)

> rt.jar contains all the RunTime classes that comprise the Java SE
>   platform’s core API’s. In simple terms this is the jar which contains
>   classes like java.lang.String, java.io package etc.

Comment: Do you know where i can download such JAR file?

Comment: You should have it automatically if your JDK is v6 or above

Answer (score 0):

Could be Java SE or Apache Xerces or AWT

They all have the same class within same package.